# Don't print headings below a specified level but keep them in PDF document outline

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, bookmarks

I have a document in which I have a fairly deep hierarchy of `/section`, `/subsection`, `/subsubsection`, `/paragraph`, etc that I have been using to help organize the writing. For the final output, I only want headings for sections and subsections to appear in the printed output and table of contents, but I want to retain all headings in the PDF document outline.

I know how to suppress sections from the table of contents, using `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`, however this also removes the headings from the PDF document outline, and doesn't suppress any headings.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref} %pdf index
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\subparagraph{subparagraph}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

This outputs a document like this:

> ## Contents
>
> 1. section
>
>    1. subsection
>
> ## 1. section
>
> ### 1.1 subsection
>
> #### 1.1.1 subsubsection
>
> **paragraph**
>   **subparagraph** Lorem ipsum dolor ...

and the PDF document outline only contains section and subsection.

What I want is this:

> ## Contents
>
> 1. section
>
>    1. subsection
>
> ## 1. section
>
> ### 1.1 subsection
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor ...

but with a PDF document outline containing section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, and subparagraph.

Comment: You mean the `bookmarks`, not the `pdf index`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are correct in that 'index' is not the correct word. According to the PDF reference manual the correct term for the feature is 'Document Outline'.

Comment: Yes, that's even better.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `bookmark` package and say `\bookmarksetup{depth=5}` to keep all the bookmarks down to `\subparagraph` level -- this works independently of the `tocdepth` setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=5]{hyperref} %pdf index
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\bookmarksetup{depth=5}
\tableofcontents
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\subparagraph{subparagraph}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]